# Django Class View Issue with Getting Request Object

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I trying to implement a **class view** which inherits form **FormView**. My problem is that I need to add the **request.user** to **ContactUploadForm** I have tried:

```
ContactUploadForm(request.user) and ContactUploadForm(self.request.user)
```

**However, how do I get request? I don't see how these will work.**

```
class ImportFromFile(FormView):
    """
    Class view import that allows a user to upload a single file (CSV, Excel) of contacts to a group.
    Inherits :FormView: - A view for displaying a form, and rendering a template response.
    """
    template_name = 'contacts/import_file.html'
    form_class = ContactUploadForm(request.user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that:

```
class ImportFromFile(FormView):
    ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ImportFromFile, self).get_form_kwargs():
        kwargs.update({
            'user': self.request.user
            ...
        })
        # or if you want to set only user
        # kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
    ...
```

Updated:
You should override [get_form_kwargs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) method.

You can also override get_form:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({
            'user': self.request.user
            ...
    })
    # or if you want to set only user
    # kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return form_class(**kwargs)
```

But I think overriding get_form_kwargs is more understandable and easy because you don't need to know about implementation of parent method (encapsulation) if you override get_form you have to.

Comment: I see, so get_form_kwargs and not get_form method?

Comment: Yes, in this case you should override get_form_kwargs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use braces mixins :

http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#userformkwargsmixin

That will spare you the trouble of repeating stuff for every view/form where you need to access user info.

Comment: This is a very interesting project.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that at the class level. The form-based views define a [`get_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form) method that you can override, within which you can access the request as `self.request`.

Comment: But its required in the forms __init__ i.e. def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs): So it needs to be created in form creation right?

Comment: `get_form` should return an *instantiated* form. So you can pass the user in there.